# Kafka Consumer Properties to read from the maximum offset

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have written a Java Kafka Consumer. I would like to make sure how to explicitly ensure that once the Kafka Consumer is started it only reads the messages which are sent by the producer from that time onwards i.e. it should not read any messages which have already been sent by the producer to Kafka. Can anyone explain how to ensure this? :

Here is a snippet of the properties I use

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("zookeeper.connect", zookeeperHost);
properties.put("group.id", group);
properties.put("auto.offset.reset","largest");
ConsumerConfig consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig(properties);
consumerConnector = Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(consumerConfig);
```

UPDATE Sept14:

I am using the following properties, it seems that the consumer still reads from the beginning at times, can someone tell me what's wrong now?

I am using Kafka Version 0.8.2

```
properties.put("auto.offset.reset","largest");
properties.put("auto.commit.enable","false");
```

Comment: you already done that. properties.put("auto.offset.reset","largest");

Comment: You should also turn off auto-commit and never commit manually, because in that case your consumer will ignore the `auto.reset.offset` config after restart and pick up the committed offset instead.

Comment: @serejja Thanks for the input

Comment: @ShawnGuo Thanks for the input, I think it seems to work with both these properties set.

Comment: @ShawnGuo please have a look at my update, I cannot identify a pattern but it does not seem to consistently work, even with these properties.

Comment: Have a look into https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/apache-kafka/5449/consumer-groups-and-offset-management#t=201609161901286026997 for some background info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on answers above, it seems that the correct mechanism is as follows for setting properties of the consumer:

```
 properties.put("auto.offset.reset","largest");
 properties.put("auto.commit.enable","false");
```

This ensures reading from the maximum offset